# how to get indexnumber form the NSCombobox?

Tags: cocoa

i have implemented nscombobox now i want to get indexnumber on selected item ow it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSComboBox` has a method `indexOfSelectedItem` you can call

[NSComboBox Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html)